# FFMPEG (windows7) can't get the output video to show more than 3 out of 10 jpgs

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, jpeg

I have 10 jpg files (image0.jpg, image1.jpg, image2.jpg ... image9.jpg) and one .mp3 and I'm trying to create a video but I can't get it to show more than the first 3 images in the output.

I played with the output `-r` option and for example if I change it to `30` it shows all of them but very fast so the whole video plays for under a second.

This is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i image%d.jpg -i audio.mp3 -r 1 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -r 1/5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The complete console output is missing, but the issue is probably the frame rate conversion from 25 to 1/5, thus resulting in dropped frames. Remove `-r 1/5` and add `-framerate 1/5` as an input option (before `-i`). If crappy WMP doesn't like it, then add `-r 25` as an output option to make a more "standard" output frame rate.

Comment: Yep, that was it, thank you  !  I see you are quite skilled with ffmpeg so can you please take a look at this [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33333371/4805488) ?

Answer (score 0):

The [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) by default uses a frame rate of 25 fps if you do not tell it otherwise. Since you used `-r 1/5` as an output option the frame rate will be converted resulting in duplicated or, as in your case, dropped frames to compensate. To change this use `-framerate` as an input option (this is a [private option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#AVOptions) of the image file demuxer):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i image%d.jpg output
```

Some crappy players may not like a "non-standard" frame rate, so you can add an output frame rate to change it while keeping the "timing" of the input:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i image%d.jpg -r 25 output
```